# How to debug INSERT statements

Tags: mariadb, bulk-insert, debugging

I have issues importing "not-so-small" dumps to MariaDB 10.4.6 in CentOS, but the error log and *stderr* is empty.

I dumped many databases with `mysqldump` sized around 50MB / 500.000 rows each, and tried to import them to my MariaDB server in a VPS. The problem is for tables that have many consecutive large `INSERT` statements, only the last one gets inserted, all the previous `INSERT` for the same table are completely ignored. I tried importing the same dump in my local machine to the same MariaDB version in Arch-linux and it works (the configuration variables are the same in both servers*). Tried setting `max_allowed_packet=1G` and adding `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` surrounding each sequence of `INSERT`, but the results are the same. The only way it works is running by hand each `INSERT` one by one. I spent many hours already googling and trying many different configurations without success.

So, my question is: is there any way to debug why all the previous `INSERT` are being ignored when I import the full dump? Any ideas?

---

* I checked it making a diff of the output of `mysqladmin variables` of both servers.

Comment: What UNIQUE keys are on the table?

Comment: Only the primary keys of each table (id, unsigned int with auto increment). But the problem is with the server, not with the dump (I had success importing it locally). Thanks!

Comment: I know you said you have the same configuration on both servers, but this may have been different in the past when the data was originally written to your source database. Specifically, sql_mode could have changed. You could try to do `SET sql_mode='';` Not sure, but I wonder if [`sql_warnings = ON`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#sql_warnings) might be helpful for debugging?